# Error C4703 potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'y' used

Tags: c++, windows, initialization

I'm getting an error potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'y' used & potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'z' used, in the code provided below. Please help me with the solution?

```
UINT8* x = new UINT8[512];
if (!x) goto clean;

//UINT32* y = NULL;
UINT32* y = new UINT32[4];
if (!y) goto clean;

//char* z = NULL;
char* z = new char[512];
if (!z) goto clean;

{.... Some Code....}

clean:

    if (x) delete[] x;
    if (y) delete[] y;
    if (z) delete[] z;
```

Comment: don't use goto should solve your problem

Comment: Did you come from 33 years ago? is the story repeating again?

Comment: if any but the last `goto` triggers you `delete[]` an unitialized pointer. If thats fine for you (i hope not) then you can ignore the warning, otherwise use RAII instead of `goto`

Comment: actually this is the best example for the evilness of `goto` I encountered so far. I wasnt even aware that `goto` enables to jump over a declaration but still use the variable later

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move all the initializations to the beginning. Otherwise with `if (!x) goto clean;` and jumps to `clean`, `y` and `z` are still not initialized.

```
UINT8* x = NULL;
UINT32* y = NULL;
char* z = NULL;

x = new UINT8[512];
if (!x) goto clean;

y = new UINT32[4];
if (!y) goto clean;

z = new char[512];
if (!z) goto clean;
```

---

PS: As others pointed, in modern C++, raw pointers (and `new` and `delete`), and `goto` should not be used in general. You might want to refer to [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/3309790).

Answer (score 3):

For reference, here's the 21st century version:

```
std::vector<std::uint8_t> x {512};
std::vector<std::uint32_t> y {4};
std::vector<char> z {512}; // Or std::string
```

Notice the lack of `clean:`. This is intentional. The compiler inserts clean-up code.

Comment: And `std::array` for 2011 version.

Comment: @songyuanyao: I'm converting like for like. Presumably the old code had good reason to put these containers on the heap, so I kept that. The whole point of RAII is that you can get the semantics of local variables even with heap allocation.

Answer (score 2):

If you jump to `goto` from here:

```
if (!x) goto clean;
```

Then `y` and `z` would have never been initialized here:

```
if (x) delete[] x;
if (y) delete[] y;
if (z) delete[] z;
```

---

The real answer to this question is: do not use `goto`, especially in C++. Use `std::unique_ptr` instead to manage your memory automatically.

Comment: Can you also provide me an example for using std::unique_ptr, I'm new to coding!